# C# function returns an empty document

Tags: c#

I have a WCF service that returns documents and images stored in a SQL Database. I am able to return all of the images with no problem. When it comes to the documents, I am able to return the document, but it is empty when I open it. The file size is correct when stepping through the code, and when opening the document it has the correct number of pages as well. Just all blank.

Here is what I am using to get the documents:

```
String folderPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"].ToString();

 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);

 FileStream fs = new FileStream(folderPath + "1" + fileExt,FileMode.Create ,FileAccess.Write);

 byte[] bytes = new byte[ms.Length];

 fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

 fs.Flush();

 ms.Flush();

 fs.Close();

 ms.Close();
```

I have also tried it with .pdfs and it tells me that the file may be corrupt and doesn't open.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you need the MemoryStream? Are you writing bytes array as the response?

Comment: When you set your byte array to new byte[ms.Length]. This will only create an empty file for the length you specify. You need to fill your byte array with the actual data, not specify its length.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate bytes and then write it out. When you allocate bytes, it's an array of zeros (or perhaps an array of random bytes. Not entirely sure, but that's neither here nor there.). You never populate it.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[ms.Length];

fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Additionally, as Nikola pointed out, it looks like the MemoryStream may be unnecessary if byteArrayIn already has an array of bytes with your data, just write that out instead.